# Cambiar nombre del dispositivo desde un textbox

Tags: java, android-studio, bluetooth

Quisiera cambiar el nombre del dispositivo android(el nombre del bluetooth) desde un textbox y no se como acceder, no se si se accede desde las librerias de bluetooth o de otra libreria

Comment: Lo primero que tienes que hacer es permitirle a tu app acceder al bluetooth: <manifest ... > <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" /> ... </manifest> luego has de coger el valor del textbox y con la clase [Bluetooth Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter?hl=es-419) poner: bluetooth.setName(nombre);

Comment: ¿Pero como se cambia el nombre del dispositivo desde un textbox? Te sugiero revisar [answer]-